# How to access non SharePoint site's data from SharePoint

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, csom

How to access the external non SharePoint site's data and display in SharePoint site using REST or any approach?

Comment: get non-sharepoint data and display it using the technique ypu know? For ASP.NET use custom web.parts for javascript use content editor query webpart with javascript (many options how to connect this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used SharePoint Add In SP.WebProxy and accessed the cross domain (non-SharePoint) site.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a sharepoint issue. If you have data somewhere else then you need to find out if that service provides you an endpoint for data retrieval through REST, SOAP, .etc.

SharePoint also has [Business Connectivity Service](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee661740.aspx) that lets you connect to external databases and surface that information in SharePoint. This is a good option if you have control over this external service.